# Как установить Internet explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer

Стоял IE 9, я зашел в компоненты, удалил оттуда. В итоге IE полностью удалился с компьютера.

Мне нужен или 7 или 8. Просто скачать тоже не получается - выдает ошибку, якобы не поддерживается этой системой. Как мне установить IE 7/8 на компьютер?

Comment: Поставь на виртуальную машину(VmWare, VirtualBox,...) хп с нужной тебе версией IE :) Для тестов вполне подходит.

Comment: Кажется вам [сюда](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123019/). И почему никто не юзает гугл?

Comment: ![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/CvQVW5z.jpg

Comment: @Gorets типа намёк? :D

Comment: А зачем ??

Comment: зачем ставить ие8 или 7...если для разработки, то там в 9 можно просто нажать f12(панель разработчика) и поменять на ие7 или 8

Comment: [IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам это надо для веб-разработок, то может это подойдет https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/ie-netrenderer/